# Help IDing a high-power IC - OODOW 836 T57

Tags: identification, repair, fault, synthesizer

I'm fault finding for a [Korg M50 Synthesizer](https://www.vintagesynth.com/korg/m50).

Symptoms: on every boot a message appears saying the device is updating the left/right control panel firmware, after which it requests a re-boot. Occasionally this boot loop doesn't trigger, and the device may be useable, or the piano keys are usable (generate sound) but one or both control panels or the touch screen control panel doesn't respond.

I've located a shorted diode on the primary motherboard (`D4` on silkscreen), which is physically on the reverse side of a power IC (`IC7` on silkscreen). I'm trying to ID this power IC so I can get an appropriate replacement part.

The IC in question is surface mount, and has 5 legs and a ground plane connection. It's label reads;

> `OODOW`

> `836 T57`

[image: Power IC close-up photo]

[image: Power IC context on motherboard photo]

[image: Failed diode close-up photo]

[image: Failed diode context on motherboard photo]

Answer (score 1):

Update:

I think the device label may be `00DD0W` (zeros, not the letter 'o'), in which case, this looks like a Linear Voltage Regulator - e.g. [BA00DD0WHFP-TR from DigiKey](https://www.digikey.com.au/en/products/detail/rohm-semiconductor/BA00DD0WHFP-TR/2337069?utm_source=findchips&utm_medium=aggregator&utm_campaign=buynow). The IC also has `BA` stamped in a small circular recess in one corner, which matches the first two letters in this part number, which is encouraging.

The datasheet for this part suggests a reverse current protection diode between the VCC and OUT pins, which on this packaging are pins 2 and 4 - and I confirmed the Diode is connected between these pins.

Seems like this might be the IC.

Comment: LCSC has a [picture](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Linear-Voltage-Regulators-LDO_ROHM-Semicon-BA00DD0WHFP-TR_C509715.html) of the BA00DD0 and it looks like a match to me.